# not able to get JSON string in servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, servlets

I am trying to pass some variables through JSON from JSP to servlet through ajax call. But i am getting null value at servlet side. Please some one help me on to find out where i am making mistake/ what i missed

```js
//JSON 
  var masterdata = new Object();
     masterdata.grn = $('#grn').val();
     masterdata.pono = $('#pono').val();
     masterdata.podt = $('#podt').val();
      
//call the servlet to insert the data only when error = 0
  if (error != 1){
   $.ajax({
    url : 'insertserv',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
          data: {test : JSON.stringify(masterdata)},
          contentType: 'application/json',
          mimeType: 'application/json',
    success : function(data) {
       alert('Hi');
      }   
            });
      }
  else{
   alert("Save cannot be performed. Please check the entered data!");
  }
    });
```

```js
public class insertserv extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
 {
  System.out.println("I am inside insert");
  String masterdata = request.getParameter("test");
  System.out.println("masterdata :  "+masterdata);
  
  response.setContentType("text/plain");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your ajax code with my code...

```js
//JSON 
  var masterdata = new Object();
     masterdata.grn = $('#grn').val();
     masterdata.pono = $('#pono').val();
     masterdata.podt = $('#podt').val();
      
//call the servlet to insert the data only when error = 0
  if (error != 1){
   $.ajax({
    url : 'insertserv',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify({"test" :masterdata}),
          contentType: 'application/json',
          mimeType: 'application/json',
    success : function(data) {
       alert('Hi');
      }   
            });
      }
  else{
   alert("Save cannot be performed. Please check the entered data!");
  }
    });
```

To get data in servlet

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
      String json = "";

            if (br != null) {
                json = br.readLine();
            }
 JSONObject wholedata= new JSONObject(json);
```

now the object wholedata has a your json..

if you are using JSON.stringify() then you have to use 
BufferedReader in `servlet` ,
 You can use request.getparameter in `servlet` when you are passing data in URL of `servlet`.

Comment: Thanks for given me the correct path. Could you please little more clear on how should i proceed to get all variables

Comment: To get data from `wholedata` you can do like 
`JSONObject testdata = wholedata.getJSONObject("test");`

Then to get particular element write 
`testdata .getString("grn");`

This is only for example you can do it for all your Three varibles (grn,pono,grn)

Comment: i am getting error at JSONObject wholedata= new JSONObject(json);" The constructor JSONObject(string) is undefined". and i have imported org.json.simple.*; too

Comment: hey Jsel first print the `String json` if it prints well then we are sure that our data is in servlet , if it doesn't print anydata then we have to optimize the code. 
if data will print then we can get variable's data from using code..

Comment: yes, i already verified i am getting required data. but getting above error when trying to parse it

Comment: i m not sure why you are getting this error but may be  it is because of import statement, import this `import org.json.JSONObject;` then try.
if after adding this you are not getting ans patiently check your code something is wrong there because you are very close to your ans .

if my ans is really helpful then up vote me. Thanks

Comment: fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: i could get data in json; but not further

Comment: send me the sop(json) which is type of String & also send  the sop(wholedata).. i ll check then i ll tell. would mind to share your gmail id? because i think it is better to solve this issue there compare to giving ans in comments..

Comment: now this is string type to get the 'json' type data you have to convert it in a 'JSONobject' so first Put `JSONObject wholedata= new JSONObject(json);`
line after  end of if condition .

now the whole data have same structure but type is `json` 
now put `JSONObject singledata = `wholedata.getJSONObject("test");`.
after this print singledata you ll find Structure like this `:{"grn":"56690","pono":"1722117","podt":"11-02-17"}`

to get particular variable you can do like `singledata .getInt or getLong` type of variable is depends on your data.

Comment: yes.. thanks.. i could proceed. but i am struck in that constructor error :(

Answer (score 0):

If your backend is responding with `json` content then only `dataType:"json"` works. Try change the response type:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Because your ajax is expecting json from the backend with `dataType:"json",`.

or vice-versa.

change the dataType to text: `dataType:"text",` as the response header says `response.setContentType("text/plain");`. But in this case you have to use `JSON.parse()` to parse the json string.

```js
//JSON  
var masterdata = new Object();
masterdata.grn = $('#grn').val();
masterdata.pono = $('#pono').val();
masterdata.podt = $('#podt').val();

//call the servlet to insert the data only when error = 0
if (error != 1) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'insertserv',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text', //<------change this
    data: {
      test: JSON.stringify(masterdata)
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert('Hi');
    }
  });
} else {
  alert("Save cannot be performed. Please check the entered data!");
}
});
```

Comment: changed response as application/json. still getting null

Comment: @Jsel i can see you are not returning a valid json instead change the dataType to text.

Comment: i have modified as u mentioned in snippet. but getting same null:(